# Reading csv with unicodecsv: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I have these lines of code:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(self.temp_file, 'r')
data = zf.open('myfile.csv', mode='r')
result = [link for link in unicodecsv.DictReader(data)]
```

And here's the exception code:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 13: invalid continuation byte
```

Input string is:

```
CAFÉ RESTAURANT
```

So what am I doing wrong and why `unicodecsv` can't handle utf-8?

Comment: because the content is *not* UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your input is *not* UTF-8, but Latin-1 (or similar). In UTF-8, `É` is encoded as 2 bytes: `'\xc3\x89'`. The error informs that the `\xc9` byte was met in the input; this is `É`s encoding in Latin-1 or Win-1252 codepages.